# Linux service can't load library path in the /etc/ld.so.conf.d

Tags: linux, service, library-path

I have a service in Linux.

When I start it use service start or start in `init.d`.  It can't load config which has stored in `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/`. So some process which load the library path in `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/.` can't be launched by this service.

But when I run this service script in shell, it works fine.

How to load the library path in the `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/`?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: [The problem is service strips all environment variables but TERM, PATH and LANG ](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/44378)
Useful link help why service don't work.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Did you run `ldconfig` (as root) lately? There's a shared library cache that's updated by that program, and if you updated a file in `/etc/ld.so.conf.d` without running `ldconfig`, the cache data could be out of date.

Comment: You mean I have to run ldconfig before service start? I will have a try.

Comment: No, you have to run `ldconfig` after editing `/etc/ld.so.conf` or one of the files in `/etc/ld.so.conf.d`. After that, assuming you don't change those files, you don't usually need to rerun `ldconfig`.

Comment: It doesn't work.
I run **ldconfig** before **service myserv restart**. It still not run correctly. 
I have to 
`LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/myprog/lib
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH
`
After this, it could execute

Comment: Well, that's easy, then. Add `/usr/local/myprog/lib` to a new file in `/etc/ld.so.conf.d` (maybe `myprog.conf`, if your program is really called `myprog`), then run `ldconfig`, then try again.

Comment: Also, double-check that your `/etc/ld.so.conf` includes this line: `include /etc/ld.so.conf.d/*.conf`. Without that, nothing in `/etc/ld.so.conf.d` would get loaded.

Comment: Yes. I had set the `/etc/ld.so.conf` as you said. But it didn't work.
I have to export the path, in start script. I think this may cause by service load ENV have some limit.  I will try search some document about service and env. Thanks a lot.